# How to preprocess both the components CSS and global styles using Rollup or Webpack in Svelte Compiler?

Tags: webpack, postcss, rollupjs, svelte

I believe there is an option to use a preprocessor in svelte config nowadays. But I have not managed to do it successfully yet... (Guess the community could use a working example both with Rollup and Webpack).

Before I tinker even more, I was wondering if it is possible to preprocess global.css (or any 'non-component' css) using rollup / webpack config in svelte compiler as it compiles main js?

While I do like the idea of CSS being tied to the component, there are developers who rely on global styling as much as component styling, so they don't have to repeat the styles over again in each component.

No code to show, as I would have not a clue where to start?

Comment: Not really sure I get what you were trying to ask. What do you want to do in the preprocess of global.css?

Comment: Assuming that you have some common styling to use across multiple components - you would put your css in global.css or any other css file and just refer to classes/ids/tags from your components. Preprocessor (like postcss) should at least take care of preprocessing and minifying the file during svelte compiling.

Answer (score 7):

This is not really a Svelte-specific problematic, but here's some directions on how to do it in Svelte's template.

In order to have CSS assets processed by the bundler (e.g. Rollup, Webpack...), you'll need to import the CSS files into your JS modules, and use the appropriate bundler plugin / loader to handle these imports.

Popular plugins for this task include [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss) and [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader), for their respective bundler.

I have pushed an example of using PostCSS with Rollup on branch [here](https://github.com/rixo/svelte-template-hot/tree/example-postcss) (see README for installation / usage).

In essence, here are the steps that you'll need to follow to add PostCSS support to Svelte's official Rollup template...

**Install `rollup-plugin-postcss`:**

```sh
npm install --dev rollup-plugin-postcss
```

**Add the plugin to your `rollup.config.js`:**

```js
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    svelte( ... ),
    postcss({
      extract: 'public/build/global.css',
      sourceMap: true,
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ]
}
```

Of course there are many ways this plugin can be configured, and that will depend on your project. What is shown here is just to make it work. See plugin the docs for all available options: https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss.

**Update your `index.html` to reference the processed asset:**

```html
<!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'> -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/global.css'>
```

(You can technically keep the unprocessed `global.css`, if you want to.)

**Finally, import your css source files in your js files:**

For example, in `main.js`:

```js
import './global.css';
...
new App(...)
```

This is needed for the CSS file to be included in the bundle. Otherwise, the bundler would have no idea that this file is used in your app (same as if you had a JS file that is imported nowhere -- and is not an entry point).

Obviously, JS would choke trying to import raw CSS. That's why a need a special plugin / loader to handle it.

Those are only the broad strokes, but I hope it can get you started.

Comment: This was helpful. How do you have different postcss configuration for global CSS and component CSS? For example, Extract the global CSS but inject the component CSS.

Comment: I think it is not possible in the rollup plugin of postcss. I move forward by using [postcss-cli](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli) to EXTRACT the output the global CSS to a file in dist (i.e. extract) and used the rollup plugin for the postcss to INJECT the CSS Modules

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me to load global CSS styles from rollup (when applying `preserveModules: true` for treeShaking) was using the '**rollup-plugin-styles**' plugin and the following configuration:

// *rollup.config.js*

```
   plugins: [
     styles({
        extensions: ['.css'],
        use: ['css'],
     }), …
  ]
```

// In the *package.json* you have to add the proper side effects

```
{
 "sideEffects": [
  "**/*.css",
  "**/*.css.js" //this one is very important too            
], 
 }
```

// *MyComponent.tx*

```
import '../styles/myGlobal.css';
```